# too few values in struct initializer when initialize C struct in golang

Tags: go, cgo

I have tried the following program, but it told me "too few values in struct initializer" when compiling it.

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

type p C.struct_Person

func main() {

    person := p{C.CString("Giorgis"), 30, 6, 175}
    fmt.Println(person)
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(person.name))
    fmt.Println(person.age)
    fmt.Println(person.height)
    fmt.Println(person.weight)
}
```

How can I fix this wired problem?
Additionally, when I changed type "char*" to "char", and the initializer. It works well.

```
struct Person {
    char name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};
```

Also, when I use

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
};
```

it works well too.

Anyway, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to put the field names in your struct literal.

```
person := p{name: C.CString("Giorgis"), age: 30, height: 6, weight: 175}
```

This is because an anonymous 4-byte [padding](http://c-faq.com/struct/align.html) field gets inserted between name and age.

Comment: Here's what "padding" is if you aren't familiar: http://c-faq.com/struct/align.html

Comment: Thanks @AJPennster, I added your link to the answer.